# Alter bootstrap dropdown html to include select id and option id

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I have a navigation bar in my html script which has a drop down option. This came with the bootstrap template that I'm using and I like the styling of it

```
      <nav id="navbar" class="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li class="dropdown"><a href="#"><span>Drop Down</span> <i class="bi bi-chevron-down"></i></a>
          </li>
               
      </nav>
```

As 'finding of workings' task I wanted to create a drop down menu where I can select a field.
I've got this working with this html snippet

```
<select id="innerSelect">
 <option id="firstOption" value="0">Country List</option>
```

My question is - how do I implement my country list drop-down, but with the styling of the bootstrap drop down?

Answer (score -1):

The dropdown in the navigation bar is not a select element, that dropdown can be created like this:

```
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: I want to drop down to be the style of the bootstrap drop down